# How to return Spring Specification<T> if requested object and field object have different classes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

@Entity Player has field: **Date birthday**.

Controller has method:

```
 @GetMapping("/rest/players")
public ResponseEntity<List<Player>> findAll(@RequestParam(required = false) Long after) {
    //response
}
```

I want to create method which returns players Specification whose birthday after some date, which is coming as Long:

```
private static Specification<Player> getPlayerByAfter(final Long after) {
    return ((root, query, criteriaBuilder) ->
            criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get("birthday")), ));
}
```

**How can I do it?** I'm not familiar with Spring at all, just start to learning it. I have tried to google it, but examples always comes with some **@RequestParam String** and I can't find anything with some other objects and especially if they have different classes.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution:

```
private static Specification<Player> getPlayerByBefore(final Long before) {
    return ((root, query, criteriaBuilder) ->
            criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("birthday"), new Date(before)));
}
```